# Asp.Net Core "Unable to locate Dependency jobsledger >= 1.0.0" on "dnu restore"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have attempted to change the names of my entity tables in OnModelCreating(builder) and now when I use "dnu restore" I get the following error:

```
        Unable to locate Dependency 
    jobsledger
    >= 1.0.0
```

I did some research and I think this is to do with my nuget.config.. however I have no personal context to this so I am hoping someone might have a simple answer to why this has failed twice now for me... here is the full list after entering "dnu Restore":

```
  PM> dnu restore
  Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc2-20221

  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  CACHE https://myget.org/f/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
  Restoring packages for C:\Users\simon\REPOS\JobsLedger\src\jobsledger\project.json
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='jobsledger'
  GET https://dotnetmyget.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/dotnet-core/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/jobsledger/index.json
  NotFound https://dotnetmyget.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/dotnet-core/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/jobsledger/index.json 981ms
  dnu : Unable to locate Dependency jobsledger >= 1.0.0
  At line:1 char:1
  + dnu restore
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to locat...ledger >= 1.0.0:String) [], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  Writing lock file C:\Users\simon\REPOS\JobsLedger\src\jobsledger\project.lock.json
  Restore complete, 1113ms elapsed

  Errors in C:\Users\simon\REPOS\JobsLedger\src\jobsledger\project.json


  Unable to locate Dependency
  jobsledger
  >= 1.0.0



  NuGet Config files used:
  C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config

  Feeds used:
  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  https://dotnetmyget.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/dotnet-core/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/
  PM>
```

Here is my nuget.config file after adding in the "key="DotNet=Core..." line:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <packageRestore>
      <add key="enabled" value="True" />
      <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <bindingRedirects>
      <add key="skip" value="False" />
    </bindingRedirects>
    <packageSources>
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
      <add key="DotNet-Core" value="https://myget.org/f/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <disabledPackageSources>
      <add key="MyGet" value="true" />
    </disabledPackageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </activePackageSource>
  </configuration>
```

How do I get this to dnu restore again and more importantly why did this go south in the first place? It seems to always happen when I add something to this method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
```

Comment: Anybody?  shouldnt have a crash like this when you make a change to the OnModelCreating(builder) method..

Comment: It has nothing to do with your OnModelCreating method. IT can't find a package you installed. The error message is pretty clear about that

Comment: The problems only arose when I added table name changes to the onmodelcreate method... its happened twice now and in both cases the project has to be built from a new project again.. as I cant find how to fix it..  @davidfowl wondering if you might know where to look when this happens and to fix it

Comment: Am currently doing a new windows install and VS2015 to rule out any corruption on my setup's part..